# efk---Filebeat failed to fill data into redis

Tags: efk

Filebeat failed to fill data into redis

Open the dbug query but don't know what the reason is. Help me find out why. Thanks

filebeat config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geR1C.png)
redis log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwD9A.png)

#### filebeat log

```
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:152      Run input
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:174        Start next scan
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/access_json-1.log
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/access_json-1.log, offset: 1758536
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:548        File didn't change: /application/nginx/logs/access_json-1.log
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/access_json.log
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/access_json.log, offset: 35070
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:546        Harvester for file is still running: /application/nginx/logs/access_json.log
2018-11-28T19:02:52.470+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:195        input states cleaned up. Before: 2, After: 2, Pending: 0
2018-11-28T19:02:55.468+0800    DEBUG   [harvester]     log/log.go:102  End of file reached: /application/nginx/logs/access_json.log; Backoff now.
```

Comment: Add logs/code/error messages as text, not as image

Comment: @barbsan debug  log
2018-11-28T18:54:42.433+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:548        File didn't change: /application/nginx/logs/access_json-1.log
2018-11-28T18:54:42.433+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/access_json.
log
2018-11-28T18:54:42.433+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /application/nginx/logs/ac
cess_json.log, offset: 30685
2018-11-28T18:54:42.433+0800    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:546

Comment: whatever it is post it as text

Comment: @barbsan Can't paste too much text, I can only paste parts，I am a newbie, please also give me a lot of advice.

Comment: [edit] your question instead of pasting it in comments

Comment: @barbsan The log has been pasted into the edit box

Comment: ok, just don't remove everything, only replace image links, do the same for that config file and that second log (keep it as short as possible)

Comment: @barbsan I am sorry, I am in trouble. I have re-copied the log.

Comment: I've formatted your config and log file and added back description of your issue. Feel free to rollback to any [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53517642/revisions) you want or copy that previous log into your question again (I'm a bit confused whether you want it here or that new log is enough)

Comment: #barbsan very sorry. 
Yesterday evening, I have a question, how can I solve this problem? Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: #barbsan I have found the problem because I wrote one more character.